# How to avoid double quotes when saving Excel file as Unicode?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2003

I have an Excel file with Unicode content of which some cells contain text inside double quotes, for example `"text"`.

When I save the Excel file to a text file in Unicode format, the text which contains the double quote is saved as three double quotes, for example `"""text"""`.

There are some places where I even have text which contains comma (,). For example, `text,` which is converted into `"text,"` in the Unicode file. It is adding double quotes to the text, which I guess contains special characters.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 10):

This is standard behavior (and similar to the way CSV files are saved). See the [RFC 4180 –   Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.

How does that apply to your case?

- This means that `"Text"` **must be saved** as `"""Text"""`, the outer quotes delimiting the field, and the two other quotes are used to escape the actual quotes you used for your text field. Otherwise, `"Text"` would be just parsed as `Text` and you would lose your quotes when re-opening the file.
- Excel chooses to quote `Text,` as well, because the comma is used as a delimiter in comma separated files, and not enclosing it in quotes would mean that `text,` is parsed as two fields when you re-open the file.

If you don't want them in your output, consider opening the resulting files in a text editor and removing all the quotes with a simple search-and-replace.

Comment: You mean that there is no other way to solve the issue other than replacing them in text editor.

Comment: Not really, since Excel has to do it for compatibility reasons. Maybe it might be possible to come up with a Macro that does a custom export, but I'm no expert on this.

Comment: Ok thanks may be i will try to replace it in the coding side.

Comment: @slhck: I am facing issue while saving Unicode as CSV in 2010 https://superuser.com/q/1210099/234380

Answer (score 4):

Saving to Unicode seemed to add in quotes even when there were no quotes in my string. Here's how I got around it:

1. Find a string that isn't in your file (I used `xxx`).
2. Before exporting, Find & Replace All double quotes `"` with `xxx`
3. Export your file to txt or csv.
4. Open txt files and Find & Replace All quotes with nothing
5. Find & Replace All `xxx` with quotes

Comment: Note, use `replacement` not `'replacement'`. Replacing the double quotes with something including a single quote causes issues if it happens to be at the start of a cell. Basically, Excel sees a single quote at the start of a cell meaning to interpret it as text, so it's removed when you export to txt/csv. I found this out the hard way lol.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. Then, I noticed I was overlooking the **Save as type:** option "**Formatted Text (Space delimited)**". You also **have to** specify the .**txt** extension, or it will default with a .prn extension. For example, filename.txt instead of just filename. **Try it**. **It works**.

Comment: Will be space delimited instead of tab delimited, and columns seem to be limited in width to about 8 characters by default.

Comment: This does not work if the cells contain something like `"A short sentence"`. Pete's answer below is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just easily save your file as space delimited.prn in excel and then rename it to .txt. I used this for a crisis of 18000 rows. ;)