# Excel exporting to CSV. Can I use another character than " to enclose text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

(there is a similar question in [How to avoid double quotes when saving Excel file as Unicode?](https://superuser.com/questions/349882/how-to-avoid-double-quotes-when-saving-excel-file-as-unicode), but the case described below has an issue with single doublequotes. Usually used for inch values like 3". That means I have an uneven number of doublequotes which triggers the use of doublequotes on export/save.)

When I export an excel to a csv file, I could get something like this:

```
Number;Some_text;Another_Number
1;"Hello there";33
3;"The length";77
```

That works fine as long as the second column does not contain something like 3"  (=3 inch)

So I get:

```
Number;Some_Text;Another Number
1;Hello there;33
3;The length;77
6;"This is 3""";22
```

The csv needs to be imported into another system. That system can cope with another text enclosure character (like '). What it cannot cope with is the fact that there is suddenly 3"" (two double quote) instead of 3" (one double quote)

The import would be easier, if the line would look like

```
6;'This is 3"';22
```

Can this be done?

Yes, I could postprocess the csv through a text editor, but I do have a lot of variations of the text above.

Perhaps I can teach excel to use single quotes to enclose text instead of double quotes?

If yes, how?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is specific regarding the needs of the Excel export function and the needs of your other software's import function and the way these conflict. While you may not like the answer given at the duplicate, it IS the answer to the question you've asked. I recommend that you post another question asking for assistance dealing with how to justify data between these two systems.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my take from the linked question is that you have to replace the single "for inches with """ (3 of them).